# Google Chrome not returning results for queries of more than one element

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome

For some reason, Google Chrome is not returning DOM results when more than one element is requested.

For example, `document.getElementById()` and `document.querySelector()` work, but `document.querySelectorAll()`, `document.getElementsByTagName()`, and `document.getElementsByClassName()` do not work.

Below is a screenshot of the JavaScript console I was using to test the page. Additionally, the page works flawlessly in Safari, and these problems do not persist there.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is this every site or just the one you are developing locally? I don't have the same issue running the commands in the console on this page, chrome version?

Comment: I'm not seeing that either. Can you provide a more complete, step-by-step guide how you get this result?

Comment: It seems to work on every other site. Chrome version: 18.0.1025.142

Comment: In terms of how I got this result, I opened up my webpage and then the JavaScript console, and typed the commands you see above

Comment: I would suggest that you create a jsFiddle with some sample HTML in it and then document which functions are working or not working with JS code in the jsFiddle.  Those methods you're talking about all work in Chrome so there's something wrong with the specifics of what you're doing that we can't help you debug just from a screen shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that the problem was in the display of the arrays in the JavaScript console, not their actual values. This issue is documented here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121292